# os.walk syntax error python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-os

I am trying to get all directories from a specified root, this seems to run fine when I run it on windows by giving it a path, however when I move it to the raspberry pi I get a syntax error

```
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/pi/", topdown=False)
                                                           ^
```

I have been following this but not sure if I have been doing it correct: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm, I have only just started with python so not sure what is wrong.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/pi/", topdown=False)
    for name in dirs:
        if name == "MyDir":
            createFolder = os.path.join(root, name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `:` after your `for` loop

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/pi/", topdown=False)
                                                            ^
```

Comment: Cannot believe I did not spot that. Thanks